# jboss Log handler is already assigned when working wuth jboss-cli

Tags: logging, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

4-eap and i want to automatize the standalone instance configuration ising a script file oassed to jboss-cli with the commend:

> jboss-cli.sh -c --file="my file"

into this file i have a handler and a logger that i want to add on it, like this way:

```
if (outcome!=success) of /subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=IDTS_FILE_HANDLER:read-resource
echo "adding Log Handler"
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=IDTS_FILE_HANDLER:add(file={"path"=>"idts/j/log/idts.log","relative-to"=>"var.opt"},formatter="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{2} [%X{USER}][%X{OPERATION}] %s%E%n",suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd")
else
echo "Log Handler already present"
end-if

if (outcome!=success) of /subsystem=logging/logger=it.idts:read-resource
echo "adding logger"
/subsystem=logging/logger=it.idts:add   
/subsystem=logging/logger=it.idts:write-attribute(name="level", value="DEBUG")
/subsystem=logging/logger=it.idts:assign-handler(name="IDTS_FILE_HANDLER")
reload
else
    echo "logger already present"
end-if
```

i obtain this output:

```
"adding Log Handler"
"adding logger"
if request failed: {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-3" => "JBAS011536: Handler IDTS_FILE_HANDLER is already assigned."}}
```

It tells me that the handler is already assigned, but this is not true,
but the logger isn't present in my file (i started with a base standalone.xml) I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of EAP are you having an issue on?

Comment: i am using jboss eap 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the way the add operation functions. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-37 for details.

The simplest workaround would be to add the `handler` parameter to the `add` operation.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=it.idts:add(handlers=["IDTS_FILE_HANDLER"], level=DEBUG)
```

In fact that gets rid of the extra write parameter too.

FWIW the `reload` command is not needed for adding a new logger or file handler. Those are updated at runtime.